# After convert float to string in C# I get -0 result

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("PLEASE, TYPE R NUMERIC INTEGER — COEFFICIENT:");
R = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("PLEASE, TYPE S NUMERIC INTEGER — COEFFICIENT:");
S = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

float R_0 = (float)R; //PROTECTION FROM ZERO-VALUE IN DivideByZeroException BY USING FLOAT NUMERIC VARIABLES INSTEAD, FLOAT IS A DIFFICULT TYPE TO CALCULATE ZERO SO ITS CAN BE DIVIDED ON TO.
float S_0 = (float)S;

x_1 = -S_0 / R_0;

//string x_1s = x_1.ToString();
//double x_1d = (double)x_1;

return $"In case of the different equation {R}x + ({S}) = 0, the root is {x_1}.";
```

After this I always getting result "***-0***", when, for an example ***R = 10*** and ***S = 0***, but it should be "***0***" instead.

I have tried to change float value to double, and I have tried to create standalone string variable and only then place in the ***return*** program of the method. Nothing helps.

Comment: This seem to depend on .net version used. In .Net 4.8 `(-0f).ToString()` results in "0", while .Net core 3+ result in "-0". Note that floating point numbers have both negative and positive zero, so printing `-0f` as "-0" is perfectly resonable.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/corefx#floating-point-formatting-and-parsing-behavior-changed

Comment: Interesting! Looks stupid, but interesting! Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check 3 edge cases separately and then compute general solution:

```
Console.WriteLine("PLEASE, TYPE R NUMERIC INTEGER — COEFFICIENT:");
R = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("PLEASE, TYPE S NUMERIC INTEGER — COEFFICIENT:");
S = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (S == 0 && R == 0) return "any value";
if (S == 0 && R != 0) return "the root is 0";
if (S != 0 && R == 0) return "no solution";

return $"In case of the different equation {R}x + ({S}) = 0, the root is {-1.0 * S / R}.";
```

Comment: No of course. You typing things that not related ot my question Mr. ASh, actually program to solve quadratic equation was created before I even know about if-else branching, so no any if-else in the code and actually it is only a part of program on my post above, if I will make such nonsense code that proposing in that part — it will be collapse of the program... xD

Comment: admitting not knowing basic thing and then mocking someone else code = incompetence + arrogance

Comment: Mr. @ASh, cycles is not the 'basics' in this case, because nothing mentioned it in basic condition of the solution of the problem.